# Dynamic IVR menu application in MVC using twilio API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to develop an application in MVC4 where client can configure Dynamic menu for Incoming Calls from user Interface using Twilio API. Is there any opensource project exist or any voice model  for dynamic IVR menu from where i can get an idea and application flow for GUI design. Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To my knowledge there isn't a .Net project that demonstrates how to build an IVR using Twilio. however, there are a few tutorials showing how to do it, and because most of it uses TwiMl, you should just be able to generate that using the libraries, or by simply making your requests return such verbs when necessary.

I would definitely stat off by looking at the following:

- [Project: Build a Simple IVR](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/build-a-simple-ivr/1.html) The example is in PHP, but you should very easily be able to translate that into C#
- [IVR: The Basics](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ivrs-the-basics) A good resource that tells you how IVR's actually work
- [Build an IVR system with Twilio and Django](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/build-an-ivr-system-with-twilio-and-django.html) Another tutorial showing how to build an IVR using Django

With the URLs above you should be ale to get your IVR up and running in no time, but by all means feel free to reach out to me if you need any help. I'm a C# developer myself, so will be able to assist you if you get stuck with anything.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. This helped me alot. I am more concerned now about screen design for IVR menu.How to design multi level menu screen for IVR.

Comment: I think that will depend quite a lot on your needs. Do you have any specs?